# No route matches [GET] "/zombie"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Earlier it was working fine. I don't know what happen but I get this error now.

Rails.root: /Users/abhimanyuaryan/RubymineProjects/TwitterBy

[image]

Comment: post your `routes.rb` file and the view file where this error is occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer, your problem is that you're trying to access `/zombie` when the routes are either `/zombies` or `/zombie/:id`.

---

I wanted to add that if you're a beginner, the routes system can seem a little confusing...

[image]

The way to understand it is that **Rails *catches* URL routes** you send it. Rails is not magic, it's built on top of the [HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol), and as such you can only send *urls* to your app, such as `/zombies` or `/zombie/:id`

Rails uses the [ActiveDispatch middleware](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) to take the URL's coming to the app, and *routing* them to a `controller/action`, where your code resides. Rails then takes the rendered HTML from your code and returns it to the browser, allowing the user to interact with their data etc.

The important thing to note is that **Rails can only work with what you send it**.

The [Routes documents](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) are a good step on seeing how this works; ultimately, you have to understand that you're responsible for sending the right URL's to rails, which can be achieved quite simply with the [path helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#path-and-url-helpers).

---

**Objects**

Finally, I also wanted to showcase something else - [*object orientation*](http://superprofundo.com/2010/12/09/object-oriented-programming-in-a-nutshell/).

[image]

Rails is built on [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/), which makes both of them [object orientated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming). This is a programming pattern made popular with video games.

The counter to *object orientated programming* is [*flow based programming*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow-based_programming), which puts the *flow* of an application at the center of design. Typical "native" apps are flow-based, whilst games are object orientated.

The technical difference between the two is that object orientated programs store a series of "objects" (variables) in memory, allowing the user to "interact" with them.

Flow based design *may* keep just as much data in memory, but will only let the user access it through certain flow interactions. The best example of this would be the likes of *setup/installation* applications.

Anyway, because *Ruby* is object orientated, Rails has been designed to be such as well. Once you understand this, everything becomes *much* simpler.

Instead of thinking of Rails as controllers/variables/data, you want to think in terms of *objects* -- **which *object* am I interacting with?**

This is why most of Rails is built in a certain way -- to make the manipulation of *objects* work much smoother:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :zombies #-> provides routes to interact with Zombie objects

#app/controller/zombies_controller.rb
class ZombiesController < ApplicationController
   def index
      @zombies = Zombie.all #-> show ALL zombie objects
   end

   def show
      @zombie = Zombie.find params[:id] #-> find a single zombie object
   end

   def new
      @zombie = Zombie.new #-> new zombie object
   end

   def create
      @zombie = Zombie.new zombie_params
      @zombie.save #-> save the new Zombie object
   end

   private

   def zombie_params
      params.require(:zombie).permit(:zombie, :params)
   end
end

#app/models/zombie.rb
class Zombie < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :enemies #-> each zombie object has many enemies
end
```

See how it all fits together?

If you focus on the *object* rather than the flow, it becomes much simpler.

Answer (score 3):

The path in the error message is "/zombie"  but all of your paths 
use "/zombies"

you might want to modify the various id paths /zombies/:id(.format) to
be /zombie/id(.format).  that's matches rails way of doing thing.

hth

Comment: how do you create the app? maybe you are using the plural in your generate?

Comment: the paths are all consistent, but then you cannot access anything using "/zombie" as a path -- you should use "/zombies" or "/zombies/<num>"